# Using Value of a Date Picker/Time Picker

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I got this Date and Time Picker in my code:

```
    <DatePicker id="datePicker" placeholder="{i18n>enterDate}" width="15%">
            <layoutData>
                <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
            </layoutData>
        </DatePicker>
        <TimePicker id="timePicker" placeholder="{i18n>enterTime}" width="15%">
            <layoutData>
                <FlexItemData growFactor="0" />
            </layoutData>
        </TimePicker>
```

From the API reference I was not able to understand how I can use the values the user types in....

what I did is this:

```
var abc = new sap.m.DatePicker();
var date = abc.getValueDate().ById("datePicker");
```

but this seems not to work.... I guess I'm doing something horribly wrong here

Comment: add in plnkr.co or jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var abc = this.byId("datePicker"); // 'this' - is your controller instance
var date = abc.getDateValue();
```

First, you get an instance of your date picker - it loaded in XML view, and then you obtain the date entered.